# Jest test Error Receiving 404 but expected 200

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I'm writing tests using Jest & Supertest for some API's I've created in Node and I've written the test below but I keep receiving a 404 code instead of the expected 200 and I'm not sure why. I have my server running on the 3000 port and the URL is correct, so I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

This is the test

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../server");

describe("/users", () => {
  it("should get all users", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get("/api/users/");
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    expect(response.body.name).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

This is my server.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

console.log(port);

  mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://hannahosibodu68:AAQTFyw7hschIcJS@cluster0.yertzeh.mongodb.net/locationapp?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(port);
    console.log("Connected to database");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  module.exports = app;
```

This is my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParder = require("body-parser");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const app = require("./server");

const placesRoutes = require("./routes/places-routes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user-routes");

const HttpError = require("./model/http-error");

app.use(bodyParder.json());

app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE");
  next();
});

app.use("/api/places", placesRoutes);

app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
```

This is my package.json scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --testTimeout=5000",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```